# Unity 4.6+: How to disable/enable GUI panel with a UI button by script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am just starting with unity and having problems to show/hide menu panel with a button click.

I am using unity 5 and able to do it by playing On Click() button parameter right in the inspector:

I click "+", drag my panel in object field, and the select GameObject > SetActive(Bool) function.

However what I am looking to learn is the way to achieve similar behavior with C# script. I tried:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.Events;
 using System.Collections;

 public class closebutton : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject menu;

     void OnMouseDown() {
         menu.SetActive(false);
     }

 }
```

but nothing happens...

Please help me to achieve this basic task :)

Comment: The way you are already doing it is better (in inspector with onClick). It's okay to do this for learning but there might be better stuff to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are already doing it is better (in inspector with onClick).

If you are just curious then you can do the following:

```
void Start()
{
    GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => {
                                                         menu.SetActive(false);
                                                     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Sweet. Also, I think it works if you pass just a function name in there. Like AddListener(theGameObject.theFunction); That might be a bit closer to home if you are learning.